# Parse an ISO 8601 date-time with optional fractional second using ICU

Tags: c++, icu, iso8601

I used `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` format string with **icu::SimpleDateFormat**.

Though it works for date-time strings with fractional digits. Examples:

> 2016-03-31T15:04:32.049Z
>
> 2016-03-31T15:04:32.05Z
>
> 2016-03-31T15:04:32.3Z

It doesn't parse strings without fractional second (e.g. `2016-03-31T15:08:51Z`), returning an error code *U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR*.

I tried some other format combinations to no avail: some fail with an error code, others ignore milliseconds.

Does ICU even support parsing of an optional fractional second?

Comment: This [free, open-source, header-only C++11/14/17 library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) will do it with the syntax string `"%FT%TZ"`.  Just parse into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

Comment: I expect that the final solution is going to involve trying to parse with multiple parsers... first using trying one that specifies seconds, and next without.  However, I've been getting the U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR when I tried this as well, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong either.  I expect the problems are similar, so I'm putting a bounty on this.   The formats I am using are from https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 1):

Going through ICU's [documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime/), I did not find any way how to input optional part in pattern specification.

However, this problem can be solved in many different ways on the application level. One of such ways (simplified) is using multiple datetime parsers as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "unicode/datefmt.h"
#include "unicode/smpdtfmt.h"

int main() {

    UErrorCode err(U_ZERO_ERROR);

    UnicodeString patternWithMilliseconds("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    UnicodeString patternPlane("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssX");

    // init ICU parsers
    std::vector<SimpleDateFormat*> parsers = {
            new SimpleDateFormat(patternWithMilliseconds, err),
            new SimpleDateFormat(patternPlane, err)
    };

    // get dates to convert
    std::vector<UnicodeString> dates = {
            UnicodeString("2016-03-31T15:04:32.049Z"),
            UnicodeString("2017-10-30T15:05:33Z"),
    };

    SimpleDateFormat resultFormatter(patternWithMilliseconds, err);

    for(const auto& date : dates) {

        UDate parsedDate;
        UnicodeString result;
        std::string resultConverted;

        for(const auto& parser : parsers) {
            err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
            parsedDate = parser->parse(date, err);
            if (err <= 0) break;
        }

        resultFormatter.format(parsedDate, result);
        result.toUTF8String(resultConverted);

        std::cout << resultConverted << std::endl;
    }

    for(auto& parser : parsers) {
        delete parser;
    }

    return 0;
}
```